# Combine 2 queries to get data in same row in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have created 2 queries result set is like below:

Query 1:

```
ID Name Value Choice
1  abc   10    x
2  def   20    x
```

Query 2:

```
ID1 Name1 Value1 Choice1
1  eft   10    y
2  bgf   20    y
```

I have added a full outer join and result set is like

```
ID   Name Value Choice ID1  Name1 Value1 Choice1
1    abc   10    x     null null   null    null
2    def   20    x     null null   null    null
null null  null  null  1     eft     10    y 
null null  null  null  2     bgf     20    y
```

But I need like below:

```
ID   Name Value Choice ID1  Name1 Value1 Choice1
1    abc   10    x     1     eft     10    y 
2    def   20    x     2     bgf     20    y
```

Not sure on what join or logic should I use.

Comment: Please show us the original two queries, ideally along with sample data.

Comment: Add `row_number()` to both queries and `full join` them using this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your FULL JOIN condition looks like.  However, if you want to "get records side by side" (as stated in your comment) you could do something like ...

```
select *
from (
  select 1 as id, 'abc' as name, 10 as value, 'x' as choice from dual union all
  select 2, 'def', 20, 'x' from dual
) Q1 full outer join (
  select 1 as id1, 'eft' as name1, 10 as value1, 'y' as choice1 from dual union all
  select 2, 'bgf', 20, 'y' from dual
) Q2
  on Q1.id = Q2.id1 
;

-- result
ID  NAME  VALUE  CHOICE  ID1  NAME1  VALUE1  CHOICE1  
1   abc   10     x       1    eft    10      y        
2   def   20     x       2    bgf    20      y
```

That, of course will give you some NULLs for IDs that don't "match". Eg (same join, data different)

```
select *
from (
  select 1 as id, 'abc' as name, 10 as value, 'x' as choice from dual union all
  select 2, 'def', 20, 'x' from dual union all
  select 4, '_4_', 40, 'g' from dual
) Q1 full outer join (
  select 1 as id1, 'eft' as name1, 10 as value1, 'y' as choice1 from dual union all
  select 2, 'bgf', 20, 'y' from dual union all
  select 5, '_5_', 50, 'z' from dual
) Q2
  on Q1.id = Q2.id1 
;

ID    NAME   VALUE   CHOICE  ID1   NAME1  VALUE1  CHOICE1  
1     abc    10      x       1     eft    10      y        
2     def    20      x       2     bgf    20      y        
NULL  NULL   NULL    NULL    5     _5_    50      z        
4     _4_    40      g       NULL  NULL   NULL    NULL
```

Ponder Stibbon's (thank you!) suggested solution, would probably remove some of the NULLs, but you may end up having records with different IDs in some of the resultset's rows.

```
select *
from ( 
  select id, name, value, choice, rownum row_
  from (
    select 1 as id, 'abc' as name, 10 as value, 'x' as choice from dual union all
    select 2, 'def', 20, 'x' from dual union all
    select 4, '_4_', 40, 'g' from dual
  ) 
) Q1 full join (
  select id1, name1, value1, choice1, rownum row_
  from (
    select 1 as id1, 'eft' as name1, 10 as value1, 'y' as choice1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'bgf', 20, 'y' from dual union all
    select 5, '_5_', 50, 'z' from dual
  )
) Q2 on Q1.row_ = Q2.row_
;

-- result
ID  NAME  VALUE  CHOICE  ROW_  ID1  NAME1  VALUE1  CHOICE1  ROW_  
1   abc   10     x       1     1    eft    10      y        1     
2   def   20     x       2     2    bgf    20      y        2     
4   _4_   40     g       3     5    _5_    50      z        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solution, its day off for me will try your solution tomorrow and update you

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  Enjoy your day off :-)

Answer (score 1):

You never showed us your original two queries, but I will assume that we can just wrap them as CTEs.  Given that, what you seem to need here is actually an *inner* join, not a full outer join:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    -- first query
),
cte2 AS (
    -- second query
)

SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1."Value", t1.Choice, t2.ID1, t2.Name1, t2.Value1, t2.Choice1
FROM cte2 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID1;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately I can't expose the queries, also I need full data in both the queries so inner join is not a option for me, to make things simple I need columns in both queries to merge and get records side by side

Comment: Um...inner join precisely generates the result set you want, and given that you can't show us the queries, I'm afraid that my answer (or something very similar to it) is the best you are going to get here.

Comment: but inner join excludes records but I need all records

Comment: I have given the best answer according to the data you showed us.  If you need more help, then show us the real data and queries.